# problema al enviar una petición post usando la opcion RAW en POSTMAN

Tags: post, postman, peticion, body, express.js

hace días estaba probando y todo funcionaba bien, estoy utilizando la opción RAW porque estoy enviando un objeto que esta embebido dentro de otra, a continuación dejo la imagen d como lo estoy haciendo:

[image: petición post con RAW]

El problema es que cuándo imprimo el body en node.js me la estó mostrando vacío, en cambio si envío los datos usando la opción `x-www-form-urlencoded`si los recibo en el BACK, pero como mencioné anteriormente, hace unas horas me funcionaba con la opción RAW y ahora no, lo que si noto es que el objeto en la imágen me lo muestro de color gris, y cuándo me funcionaba hace unas horas marcaba las claves y los valores con un color rojo. No se si es que toqué algo que no debía y por eso ahora no funciona. En el back estoy trabajando con express.js por si sirve de algo.

Gracias de antemano al que me pueda ayudar.

Comment: En el desplegable has puesto `text`, y eso es `json`. Tal vez por eso se te ha perdido el *formato* (los colores del objeto json)

Comment: @Benito-B Genio! era eso, sabía que había movido algo, pero ya no hallaba que mover para hacerlo funcionar nuevamente. ¡Muchas Gracias!